# using relative image url's in compiled angular in electron

Tags: html, angular, electron

I have an angular app I package as an  electron app.
I used to just run

```
ng build
```

and then copy the output directory to an electron directory electron uses to build.
using a script:

```js
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "electron": "electron .",
    "electron-build": "electron .",
    "package": "electron-builder --win"
}
```

using

```
npm run package
```

Before that I had to change the base href from "" to "/" as electron wouldn't display anything if I didn't.
This didn't use to be a problem untill I started to use images in the project.
Now I would need to change all the src="" links that used to refer to the assets folder as being way higher up in the project structure, but in the compiled angular are at the same level of the resulting html.

Is there a way to cirecumvent this need to change the src="" urls on my  elements or is there a way to add a .js file to run that does that all automatically before the

```
electron-builder --win
```

command is ran in the package script